# Schedule list of windows command line prompts to run at specified time (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, scheduler

I would like to schedule two consecutive commands that I manually process on the Windows command line.  I am trying to schedule this to run at a specific time each day but can only find ways to run entire programs using the Task Scheduler, nothing for running a few specific command line prompts.

I am doing daily data movement in two steps.

1) Export data from Teradata onto my local machine by running `fexp < fexp_export.txt` where fexp_export.txt is a parameter file used for the Teradata FastExport utility

2) Upload this data from my local machine to AWS by running `scp -i KeyPair.pem ec2-user@ip-1-2-3-4.com`

What is the easiest way to run those two commands consecutively at a specific time?

Comment: A simple Windows `.bat` file with the two commands?

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks!  Feel free to put as an answer.  Got this up and running in a matter of minutes.